# How to create multiple subsets within lapply

Tags: r, subset

I need to run the same model over multiple subsets of the data. Below is some mock data. Let's say I want to do 3 t-tests, all comparing `var1` and `var2`, but each over a subset of data based on the 3 values of `group`. What's the best way to do this?

```
d <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(10), 
            var2=rnorm(10), 
            group=sample(c(1:3), 10, replace=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(split(d,d$group), function(df) t.test(x=df$var1,y=df$var2))
```

Comment: What if I need to subset based on a condition such as `group==1` and `group==2`?

Comment: Probably just create a new variable that combines groups 1 and 2 and use that instead of `d$group`.

Comment: What I meant was to run the t.test on `group=1` and another on `group=2` but not on `group=3`. Is there a way? Thanks!

Comment: @Anh You can index the `split()` output with, e.g., `lapply(split(d,d$group)[1:2], function(df) t.test(x=df$var1,y=df$var2))`